# Positioning elements in datatables DOM options

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables and I have got everything working except for positioning the dom elements.
I want the length drop down on top right of table, information on bottom left and pagination on bottom right.

So to achieve this so far I have tried a few things but can't get hold of it. 
I also tried and get things working using [this link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

```
<"text-right"l><"clear"><"bottom"ip>
<"top"l>rt
<"text-right"l>t<"bottom"pi><"clear">
```

I know this may sound simple to someone but I am not understanding it very much. Thank for the help.

Comment: For time being until I get a proper solution I did it using jquery `$(".dataTables_length").parent("div").removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-12').addClass('text-right');`

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap or another styling framework [you need to use special markup](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)